# Spring Data JDBC - Circular Dependency in Autoconfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I got circular dependency on Spring Boot Data JDBC project in my Spring Boot Application and I don't know how to resolve it.

```
┌─────┐
|  jdbcConverter defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]
↑     ↓
|  dataAccessStrategyBean defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]
└─────┘
```

This is the dependency I'm using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.12.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.12.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Beside that I'm not using any other custom initializers/beans/etc.

Am I missing something in the configuration?

Comment: Why aren't you using the starter but individual dependencies with the risk of using incompatible versions?

Comment: There's probably more to it than just what you've shared. Can you share a small sample we can run? (+1 with Martem btw, if you're hardcoding the version, please don't and use dependency management instead).

Comment: I have updated the dependencies in the question @StephaneNicoll

Comment: Two dependencies snippet does not constitute a sample I am afraid.